# Only show items with price over average

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

My sql looks like this and I only want to show items with price over average

```
SELECT COUNT(Artikelnamn) AS 'Antal Artiklar', 
    FLOOR(SUM(Price)) AS 'Lagervärde', 
    FLOOR(MAX(Price)) AS 'Max', 
    FLOOR(MIN(Pris)) AS 'Min',
    FLOOR(AVG(Price)) AS 'Genomsnitt'
FROM Artikel
GROUP BY Price HAVING Price > AVG(Price);
```

It's especially the `GROUP BY` that doesn't work and I really have googled.

Comment: Can you describe what "doesn't work" means? Can you show sample data and desired results?

Comment: Also you should be aware that using string delimiters for column aliases is deprecated. You should use `[square brackets]` or `"double quotes"`.

Comment: Average of price over what? Over all prices? Over all prices per category? Over last month prices?

Answer (score -1):

I'm not pretty sure about what you are trying to do, but if you want to:
"how items with price over average"
it'll be:

```
SELECT * FROM Artikel WHERE price > SELECT  AVG(price ) FROM Artikel;
```

Or maybe you want to do:

```
SELECT COUNT(Artikelnamn) AS 'Antal Artiklar', 
    FLOOR(SUM(Price)) AS 'Lagervärde', 
    FLOOR(MAX(Price)) AS 'Max', 
    FLOOR(MIN(Pris)) AS 'Min',
    FLOOR(AVG(Price)) AS 'Genomsnitt' FROM Artikel 
GROUP BY Price HAVING Price > SELECT  AVG(price ) FROM Artikel;
```

Comment: Neither of these queries parse (the `AVG` query at the very least needs to be a subquery surrounded by parentheses). I'm also curious what the plans look like - it might make more sense to calculate the average up front. Also, please use `{}` for marking up code, not the quote button (`"`).